# PL/SQL, How to make a trigger print out particular column rows?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

In my particular case I need to print out the 'emp_id' and 'salary' of every employee that has a salary above 100'000. It just needs to check and then print them out.

```
CREAT OR REPLACE TRIGGER idNumber
BEFORE 
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER salary_trigger
AFTER INSERT or UPDATE OF salary, ON Employee
for each row
WHEN (salary > 100000)
DECLARE 
BEGIN 
if salary > 100000
THEN 
DBMS_OUT.PUT_LINE(salary, emp_id);
END;
/
```

Comment: What do you mean by "print"?

Comment: DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line is really only intended for debug output. It usually only gets shown on the screen if the client is set up to retrieve it and show it.

Comment: i think that printing in a trigger will actually print to the alert log (or a trace file in the udump). you cannot print out from a trigger because the trigger is running in the background and is not associated with your client application.

Answer (score 0):

Why a trigger? Surely just

```
select emp_id, salary
from Employee
where salary > 100000;
```

will do?

Comment: Well, it should also do when a new salary block with over 100'000 is added.